# "New" tag in clan info next to name. How long does it last?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How long does the "new" tag last next to players names that have joined your clan?

Answer (score 4):

A new member of a clan has the new tag for 3 days or until the player is promoted.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that it will disappear after the player is promoted, but I think the "new" tag disappears at the end of the current season (1-month period).

Comment: 3 days is when it goes away I tested it

Answer (score -2):

It leaves in about 10 days unless you're promoted

Comment: 3 days not 10...